# PySpark code very slow when used within python functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using python functions to abstract the functionalities and passing dataframe as arguments to those functions as applicable, which does some calculations and returns a new/updated dataframe back.

```
def calculate(df):
    df_new = df.select('col1', 'col2')
    df_new = df.withColumn('error', when(col(col1)!= col(col2), 1).otherwise(0))
    return df_new

def get_meta(df):
    df_meta = df.agg(sum('error').alias('error_count')).select('error_count')
    return df_meta

df = spark.read.csv('/path/to/csv')
df = df.select('col1','col2')
output_df = calculate(df)
df_meta = get_meta(output_df)

df_meta.show()
```

The issue i am facing is it is taking way too long for me to get the desired result just with 30,000 records. Sometimes i end up killing the process. But when i don't use functions, it just takes less than 2 minutes to get the same output. I am not sure why spark behaves differently when dataframes are contained within functions (obviously this is not UDFs we are talking about). Any insights on this would help.

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans of the two different methods to see how they're different? `df.explain()`